# Custom UI in Photoshop for Android UI

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Is it possible for me to create a custom UI in photoshop and implement that into Android Studio?

For example, if create a custom login/register Activity in Photoshop, can i use that UI in the app? I have tried to place it as an ImageView, however I feel that may be incorrect. I was also thinking of applying it as the "Layouts" background, however it will be distorted and out of place on larger and higher resolution devices.

[image]

I am trying to achieve something similar to this, whats the best way to do so?

Comment: How do you think the user will enter data into a static image, and how will you control various touch inputs?

Comment: You want 9-patch drawables. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: Not exactly a PhotoShop image, but an ImageView can be used, and "drawn" on dynamically (scalable for all devices) with interaction (click) with concepts like Cell's (Rect.contains() i.e.Hit tests). In fact I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes some what it is possible for beginning but it is not recommended. You can create a layout and set it as a background. 
Where there are some buttons, just drag and drop a button exactly above it and make the background of button transparent. The fields where there are edit text, you should do same i.e. drag and drop the plain edit text field.

So these all stuffs takes as of twice space then normal UI build through android itself also it will not fit for all mobile devices because picture sizes like hdpi xxhdpi ,etc. all should be managed.

The method I recommed to you is to just put a good background you want and make button through android it self.

The custom button can be created. You can refer here.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/form_elements/custom_button/

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes. **Morally, no.**

From a purely "is it possible to implement this" viewpoint, I'd say it is. Set it as a background for the parent layout, and have various sizes of the same layout for different screens in the res folder (images with different aspect ratios should take care of the scaling issues that come with using different screen sizes). Interacting with various elements without the use of XML would not be possible this way (unless you want to set up clicks for specific coordinates on the screen that correspond to buttons and other objects in the background image).

Interactions would not be possible, **at all**. No login or text entering. Just text and images. This method is possible for simply displaying text or providing short, non-scrolling information.

Is this what Google expects you to do when making apps that are accessible and feel natural? Most definitely not. Making a simple login interface via the *WYSIWYG* editor is incredibly simple, and shouldn't take too long to learn from scratch. Take it on as a challenge, it isn't hard at all, and you'll be able to create much richer interfaces that your users can actually interact with.